# Ubuntu Python Playsound error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'props'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, python-playsound

I can't use the playsound on Linux for some reason, I tried:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-gtk3
```

But still not working.

The code is pretty simple:

```
import os
import time
import  playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')
    filename = 'voice.mp3'
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

speak('hello')
```

The error:

```
<ipython-input-2-3bd586ed4a90> in <module>
      5     playsound.playsound(filename)
      6 
----> 7 speak('hello tim')

<ipython-input-2-3bd586ed4a90> in speak(text)
      3     filename = 'voice.mp3'
      4     tts.save(filename)
----> 5     playsound.playsound(filename)
      6 
      7 speak('hello tim')

~/anaconda3/envs/AI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playsound.py in _playsoundNix(sound, block)
     99         playbin.props.uri = sound
    100     else:
--> 101         playbin.props.uri = 'file://' + pathname2url(os.path.abspath(sound))
    102 
    103     set_result = playbin.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'props'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had to change the way I play the audio in Ubuntu18, the file is:

> ..../anaconda3/envs/Jarvis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JarvisAI/**init**.py

and install `mpg123`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mpg123
```

the change line 149 and 148

> playsound("tmp.mp3") with os.system('mpg123 -q tmp.mp3')

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path of the audio file.
eg.
audio_filename = "/home/assistant/audio.mp3"
and
tts.save(audio_filename)